How to get screen time on daily basis
I am developing a screen time application where the user can view their screen time on a daily basis, but I am encountering an error. The screen time should be shown on a daily basis. At 12 am midnight it should reset and set to 0 but in my case it doesn't reset and showed some screen time of the last few hours and added to the next day's screen time. I will share you the necessary code
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
    override suspend fun getAppUsageStats(date: LocalDate): List<AppUsageStats> {
        val usageStateManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager

        val startTime = date.atTime(0, 0).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
        Log.d("AppUsageStats", "Start Time Zone: ${ZoneId.systemDefault()}")
        
val endTime =
            date.plusDays(1).atTime(0, 0, 10).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()
                .toEpochMilli()
        // Log the query times to debug potential midnight reset issues
        Log.d("AppUsageStats", "Querying from $startTime to $endTime")

        // Use queryUsageStats to get detailed usage data
        val usageStatsList = usageStateManager.queryUsageStats(
            UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST,  // Use INTERVAL_DAILY here
            startTime,
            endTime
        )
        val aggregatedUsageStats = usageStatsList.groupBy { it.packageName }
            .mapValues { (_, stats) ->
                stats.fold(
                    com.example.focusapp.feature_screen_time.domain.model.UsageStats(
                        packageName = stats[0].packageName
                    )
                ) { acc, stat ->
                    acc.totalTimeInForeground += stat.totalTimeInForeground
                    acc
                }
            }

        Log.d("AppUsageStats", "Aggregated Usage Stats: $aggregatedUsageStats")

        if (aggregatedUsageStats.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Log.e("AppUsageStats", "No usage stats available for the given date")
            return emptyList()
        }
        // retrieve the list of installed apps
        val installedApps =
            context.packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        val appNameMap = installedApps.associate { appInfo ->
            appInfo.packageName to context.packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString()
        }

        val appUsageStats = aggregatedUsageStats.mapNotNull { (packageName, usageStats) ->

            val icon = try {
                context.packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                getFallbackIcon()
            }
            val appName =
                appNameMap[packageName] ?: resolveSystemAppName(packageName) ?: packageName

            if (!isSystemApp(packageName)) {

                AppUsageStats(
                    appName = appName,
                    timeSpent = usageStats.totalTimeInForeground,
                    packageName = packageName,
                    icon = icon
                )
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
        return appUsageStats
    }

